# "noskipws" works but doesn't stop in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that checks if a phrase is a palindrome or not, and in case nothing is entered or just whitespace, it should print out `"empty"`.

At first, the user should type in the number of phrases that they are going to enter (e.g. 3), and then the phrases that are to be checked.

It works just fine, but when my first input is empty, it prints out `"empty"` again and again without asking for another phrase.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int N;

    int isPalindromeCounter=0;
    int counter = 0;

    string inputString;
    cin >> N;
    cout << "\n";

    while (counter<N){
        counter++;

        cin.ignore(100, '\n');
        cin >> noskipws >> inputString;

        if (inputString.length()==0){
            cout <<"empty\n";
            continue;
        }

        int left = 0;
        int right = inputString.length()-1;

        if (inputString.length()>20){
            cout <<"error\n";
            continue;
        }

        bool isPalindrome = true;

        while (left<right){
            if (inputString[left] != inputString[right]){
                isPalindrome = false;
                cout << "no\n";
                break;
            }
            left++;
            right--;
        }

        if (isPalindrome){
            cout << "yes\n";
            isPalindromeCounter++;
        }
    }

    double percentage =  double(isPalindromeCounter)/double(counter)*100;
    if (trunc(percentage) != percentage){
        cout << setprecision(5) << percentage;
    }
    else {cout << percentage << ".000" ;}

    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

I expected that it should print `"empty"` once, and then ask for another input, but it prints `"empty"` for all the inputs.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: Why all the fuss with `trunc()`? Just set the precision and let it rip. Manually adding an arbitrary number of zeroes seems overly specific.

Comment: If you're using C++ you have access to *iterators*, more specifically the forward and reverse variety for strings. Consider what you might do if you had an iterator moving forward from the front, and one moving in reverse from the back. Would that be easier than all the indexing?

Comment: The problem comes from `cin.ignore(100, '\n');`   Why don't you use `cin.getline()` instead of that and the odd `noskipws` business?

Comment: @MichaëlRoy `cin.getline()` is for `char[]` strings.  `std::getline()` is for `std::string`.

Comment: Use sd::getline(), then.  :)